# css - give full available height

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup

Html:

```
<div id="resizable">
    <div id="fixHeightTop">Whatever</div>
    <div id="problematicDiv">Whatever</div>
    <div id="semiProblematicDiv">Whatever</div>
    <div id="fixHeightBottom">Whatever</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#resizable {
    position: relative;
}

#fixHeightTop {
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
}

#fixHeightBottom {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
}

#problematicDiv {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#semiProblematicDiv {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The #resizable div is resizable (jQuery). What I need to do is to give to problematicDiv and semiProblematicDiv a height equal to 100% - fixHeightTop height - fixHeightBottom height so I can extend it on the full height of the resizable element. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to do it. If I use height: 100% it overlaps the bottom element.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: A fiddle will be more helpful

Comment: What happens if you use height: 100% and then margin-bottom: 10px to leave some room for the fixed element?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to have two div with a fixed height and the two other divs show take up the rest of the height. If this is what you want, here is a way to do it.

```
#resizable {
   height: 80px; //this is changed by JQuery, right?
}

#fixHeightTop {
   height: 20px;
}

#fixHeightBottom {
   height: 20px;
}

#problematicDiv {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100%; //this helps the div taking up the space
}

#semiProblematicDiv {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   width: 20%;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100%; //this helps the div taking up the space
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea, try to use `position:absolute;`

```
#problematicDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%; // Now you can apply height 100%
  overflow: auto;
}

#semiProblematicDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%; // Now you can apply height 100%
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Overlaps bottom. And can't say height 95% for example because parent div is resizable and 95% may mean different things.